# spring R2DBC query by enum type

Tags: spring-data, spring-data-r2dbc, r2dbc-postgresql

My PostgreSQL contains an enum like

```
create type my_type as enum('VAL1', 'VAL2')
```

in Spring boot app, it is represented by `MyType.class enum`

I'm trying to run a simple query using `DatabasClient`

```
client.exectute("select * from table where type = :type")...
```

As an error I'm getting:

```
ceptionFactory$PostgresqlBadGrammarException: operator does not exist: type = character varying
```

Casting type to `my_type` doesn't work (both with CAST and ::)

I've already registered a specific codec for `MyType.class` which works - querying all without conditions works with the relevant `@ReadingConverter`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Neither Spring Data R2DBC nor R2DBC Postgres can map your enum type to Postgres enum types.

You can still use Postgres enum types represented as strings if you properly cast the bind value/column value on retrieval in your SQL statement.

Example:

```
client.exectute("select type::text from table where type = :type::my_type")
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your answer - r2dbc can (and is) map my enums using a custom codec. casting is not working as well. If u have an answer, It will be great to add a code example.

Comment: It will be great if u can add a Casting example. I tried all the casting methods I know of and still got character varying error

Comment: thanks, happy that my question (maybe?) resulted in a PR https://github.com/r2dbc/r2dbc-postgresql/pull/284/files